# Launchable .exe file takes 10 minutes to launch

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I've created an app on python using PyQt5 and I created a launchable file using PyInstaller using the onefile method. I also used the directory folder method (but I can't recall the code I used at the time **edit onedir). I took this at face value assuming that the dozens of packages, 3 python files included, and several thousand lines were forcing the slow boot of this app but looking at other forum questions I am no longer so sure. I am also trying to launch the app on an ssl which prevents me from installing packages so I am curious if the launchable is trying to install the packages over and over until it fails, then opens the app as it is. I am incredibly confused about this and any insight would be helpful.

Edit:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt, QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QTabWidget,
                             QGridLayout)
from superqt import QLabeledRangeSlider

from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
# from openpyxl import load_workbook
from matplotlib import ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

import superqt
# from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar


class Graph_5(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bing = 0
        self.init_graph()
        self.init_layout()

def init_graph(self):
    self.plus = QtWidgets.QPushButton("+")
    self.plus.setMaximumHeight(16777214)
    self.plus.setStyleSheet("border :3px solid black")
    self.plus.clicked.connect(self.addcanvas)
    self.minus = QtWidgets.QPushButton("-")
    self.minus.setMaximumHeight(16777214)
    self.minus.setStyleSheet("border :3px solid black")
    self.minus.clicked.connect(self.removecanvas)

    self.slider = QLabeledRangeSlider(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Vertical)
    self.slider.setFixedHeight(250)
    self.slider.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.TicksLeft)
    self.slider.setRange(0,2)
    self.slider.setValue([0,2])
    self.slider.setTickInterval(1)
    self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.change_figure)
    
    self.checkBtn_2D = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("2D")
    self.checkBtn_2D.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.ChckBox_2_Processor(1))
    self.checkBtn_3D = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("3D")
    self.checkBtn_3D.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.ChckBox_3_Processor(1))
    
    self.left_frame = Qt.QFrame()
    self.left_frame.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
    self.left_frame.setFrameStyle(Qt.QFrame.WinPanel | Qt.QFrame.Raised)
    self.left_frame.setLineWidth(2)
    self.poly_lft = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("6th Polynomial")
    self.poly_lft.clicked.connect(self.change_figure)
    
    self.actual_lft = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Actual Data")
    self.actual_lft.clicked.connect(self.change_figure)
    
    self.centroids_lft = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Centroids")
    self.centroids_lft.clicked.connect(self.change_figure)
    self.fill_lft = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Fill")
    self.fill_lft.clicked.connect(self.change_figure)
    
    self.centroids_real_lft = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Centroids")
    self.centroids_real_lft.clicked.connect(self.change_figure)
    self.fill_real_lft = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Fill")
    self.fill_real_lft.clicked.connect(self.change_figure)
    
    frame_lay = QGridLayout(self.left_frame)
    frame_lay.addWidget(self.actual_lft,0,0,1,2)
    frame_lay.addWidget(self.centroids_real_lft,1,1)
    frame_lay.addWidget(self.fill_real_lft,2,1)
    frame_lay.addWidget(self.poly_lft,3,0,1,2)
    frame_lay.addWidget(self.centroids_lft,4,1)
    frame_lay.addWidget(self.fill_lft,5,1)


    self.right_frame = Qt.QFrame()
    self.right_frame.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
    self.right_frame.setFrameStyle(Qt.QFrame.WinPanel | Qt.QFrame.Raised)
    self.right_frame.setLineWidth(2)
    self.poly_rght = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("6th Polynomial")
    self.poly_rght.clicked.connect(self.change_fig_2)
    
    self.actual_rght = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Actual Data")
    self.actual_rght.clicked.connect(self.change_fig_2)
    
    self.centroids_rght = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Centroids")
    self.centroids_rght.clicked.connect(self.change_fig_2)
    self.fill_rght = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Fill")
    self.fill_rght.clicked.connect(self.change_fig_2)
    
    self.centroids_real_rght = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Centroids")
    self.centroids_real_rght.clicked.connect(self.change_fig_2)
    self.fill_real_rght = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Fill")
    self.fill_real_rght.clicked.connect(self.change_fig_2)
    
    frame_lay = QGridLayout(self.right_frame)
    frame_lay.addWidget(self.actual_rght,0,0,1,2)
    frame_lay.addWidget(self.centroids_real_rght,1,1)
    frame_lay.addWidget(self.fill_real_rght,2,1)
    frame_lay.addWidget(self.poly_rght,3,0,1,2)
    frame_lay.addWidget(self.centroids_rght,4,1)
    frame_lay.addWidget(self.fill_rght,5,1)
    
    
    self.fig = plt.figure()
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
    
    self.slider_right = QLabeledRangeSlider(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Vertical)
    self.slider_right.setFixedHeight(250)
    self.slider_right.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.TicksLeft)
    self.slider_right.setRange(0,2)
    self.slider_right.setValue([0,2])
    self.slider_right.setTickInterval(1)
    self.slider_right.valueChanged.connect(self.change_fig_2)
    
    self.checkright_2D = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("2D")
    self.checkright_2D.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.ChckBox_2_Processor(2))
    self.checkright_3D = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("3D")
    self.checkright_3D.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.ChckBox_3_Processor(2))
    
    self.fig_2 = plt.figure()
    self.canvas_2 = FigureCanvas(self.fig_2)
    self.toolbar_2 = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas_2, self)
    
    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
    self.tableWidget.setMaximumHeight(120)
    
def init_layout(self):
    side_1 = QGridLayout()
    side_1.addWidget(self.checkBtn_2D,0,0)
    side_1.addWidget(self.checkBtn_3D,0,1)
    side_1.addWidget(self.left_frame,1,0,1,2)
    side_1.addWidget(self.slider,2,0,1,2)
    graph_lay = QVBoxLayout()
    graph_lay.addWidget(self.toolbar)
    graph_lay.addWidget(self.canvas)
    
    self.parent_widg_1 = QLabel()
    self.parent_widg_1.lay = QHBoxLayout(self.parent_widg_1)
    self.parent_widg_1.lay.addLayout(side_1)
    self.parent_widg_1.lay.addLayout(graph_lay)
    
    side_2 = QGridLayout()
    side_2.addWidget(self.checkright_2D,0,0)
    side_2.addWidget(self.checkright_3D,0,1)
    side_2.addWidget(self.right_frame,1,0,1,2)
    side_2.addWidget(self.slider_right,2,0,1,2)
    graph_lay_2 = QVBoxLayout()
    graph_lay_2.addWidget(self.toolbar_2)
    graph_lay_2.addWidget(self.canvas_2)
    
    self.parent_widg_2 = QLabel()
    self.graph_lay_right = QHBoxLayout(self.parent_widg_2)
    self.graph_lay_right.addLayout(graph_lay_2)
    self.graph_lay_right.addLayout(side_2)
    self.parent_widg_2.hide()
    
    
    add_subtract = QVBoxLayout()
    add_subtract.addWidget(self.plus)
    add_subtract.addWidget(self.minus)
    
    visual_lay = QHBoxLayout()
    visual_lay.addLayout(add_subtract)
    visual_lay.addWidget(self.parent_widg_1)
    visual_lay.addWidget(self.parent_widg_2)
    
    total_lay = QVBoxLayout()
    total_lay.addLayout(visual_lay)
    total_lay.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
    self.setLayout(total_lay)

def removecanvas(self):
    if self.canvas_2.isVisible():
        self.parent_widg_2.hide()
        return
    elif self.canvas.isVisible():
        self.parent_widg_1.hide()
    
def addcanvas(self):
    if not self.canvas.isVisible():
        self.parent_widg_1.show()
        return
    elif not self.canvas_2.isVisible():
        self.parent_widg_2.show()
        
def reset_clicked(self):
    if self.canvas_2.isVisible():
        self.parent_widg_2.hide()
    
    elif not self.canvas.isVisible():
        self.parent_widg_1.show()
        
    self.fig.clear()
    self.fig_2.clear()
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.canvas_2.draw()
    
    self.slider_right.setRange(0,2)
    self.slider_right.setValue([0,2])
    self.slider_right.setTickInterval(1)
    self.slider.setRange(0,2)
    self.slider.setValue([0,2])
    self.slider.setTickInterval(1)
    
    self.poly_rght.setCheckState(False)
    self.actual_rght.setCheckState(False)
    self.centroids_rght.setCheckState(False)
    self.fill_rght.setCheckState(False)
    self.centroids_real_rght.setCheckState(False)
    self.fill_real_rght.setCheckState(False)
    
    self.poly_lft.setCheckState(False)
    self.actual_lft.setCheckState(False)
    self.centroids_lft.setCheckState(False)
    self.fill_lft.setCheckState(False)
    self.centroids_real_lft.setCheckState(False)
    self.fill_real_lft.setCheckState(False)
    
    self.checkBtn_2D.setCheckState(False)
    self.checkBtn_3D.setCheckState(False)
    self.checkright_2D.setCheckState(False)
    self.checkright_3D.setCheckState(False)
    
    self.tableWidget.clear()
    
    try:
        del self.x_vals
        del self.col_titles
        del self.dicti
        del self.rng
    except AttributeError:
        return
    

def ChckBox_2_Processor(self, canv_ID):
    if canv_ID == 1:
        if self.checkBtn_2D.isChecked() and self.checkBtn_3D.isChecked():
            self.update_2Dfig(333,canv_ID)
            try:
                self.ax_3D_1.title.set_text("3D Plot of Pressure against Distance")
                self.ax_3D_1.set_xlabel("distance from vent [ft]")
                self.ax_3D_1.set_ylabel("Time [mins]")
                self.ax_3D_1.set_zlabel("Measured Pressure")
                self.canvas.draw()
            except AttributeError:
                True
        elif self.checkBtn_2D.isChecked() and not self.checkBtn_3D.isChecked():
            self.update_2Dfig(111,canv_ID)
            try:
                self.ax_2D_1.title.set_text("2D Plot of Pressure against Distance")
                self.ax_2D_1.set_xlabel("distance from vent [ft]")
                self.ax_2D_1.set_ylabel("Measured Pressure")
                self.canvas.draw()
                # print(self.ax_2D_1)
            except AttributeError:
                True
                
        elif not self.checkBtn_2D.isChecked() and self.checkBtn_3D.isChecked():
            self.fig.clear()
            self.update_3Dfig(111,canv_ID)
            try:
                self.ax_3D_1.title.set_text("3D Plot of Pressure against Distance")
                self.ax_3D_1.set_xlabel("distance from vent [ft]")
                self.ax_3D_1.set_ylabel("Time [mins]")
                self.ax_3D_1.set_zlabel("Measured Pressure")
                self.canvas.draw()
            except AttributeError:
                True
        elif not self.checkBtn_2D.isChecked() and not self.checkBtn_3D.isChecked():
            self.fig.clear()
            self.canvas.draw()
    
    elif canv_ID == 2:
        if self.checkright_2D.isChecked() and self.checkright_3D.isChecked():
            self.update_2Dfig(333,canv_ID)
            try:
                self.ax_3D_2.title.set_text("3D Plot of Pressure against Distance")
                self.ax_3D_2.set_xlabel("distance from vent [ft]")
                self.ax_3D_2.set_ylabel("Time [mins]")
                self.ax_3D_2.set_zlabel("Measured Pressure")
                self.canvas_2.draw()
            except AttributeError:
                True
        elif self.checkright_2D.isChecked() and not self.checkright_3D.isChecked():
            self.update_2Dfig(111,canv_ID)
            try:
                self.ax_2D_2.title.set_text("2D Plot of Pressure against Distance")
                self.ax_2D_2.set_xlabel("distance from vent [ft]")
                self.ax_2D_2.set_ylabel("Measured Pressure")
                self.canvas_2.draw()
            except AttributeError:
                True
        elif not self.checkright_2D.isChecked() and self.checkright_3D.isChecked():
            self.fig_2.clear()
            self.update_3Dfig(111,canv_ID)
            try:
                self.ax_3D_2.title.set_text("3D Plot of Pressure against Distance")
                self.ax_3D_2.set_xlabel("distance from vent [ft]")
                self.ax_3D_2.set_ylabel("Time [mins]")
                self.ax_3D_2.set_zlabel("Measured Pressure")
                self.canvas_2.draw()
            except AttributeError:
                True
        elif not self.checkright_2D.isChecked() and not self.checkright_3D.isChecked():
            self.fig_2.clear()
            self.canvas_2.draw()      
        
    
def ChckBox_3_Processor(self, canv_ID):
    if canv_ID == 1:
        if self.checkBtn_3D.isChecked() and self.checkBtn_2D.isChecked():
            self.update_3Dfig(333,canv_ID)
            try:
                self.ax_2D_1.title.set_text("2D Plot of Pressure against Distance")
                self.ax_2D_1.set_xlabel("distance from vent [ft]")
                self.ax_2D_1.set_ylabel("Measured Pressure")
                self.canvas.draw()
            except AttributeError:
                True
        elif self.checkBtn_3D.isChecked() and not self.checkBtn_2D.isChecked():
            self.update_3Dfig(111,canv_ID)
            try:
                self.ax_3D_1.title.set_text("3D Plot of Pressure against Distance")
                self.ax_3D_1.set_xlabel("distance from vent [ft]")
                self.ax_3D_1.set_ylabel("Time [mins]")
                self.ax_3D_1.set_zlabel("Measured Pressure")
                self.canvas.draw()
            except AttributeError:
                True
        elif not self.checkBtn_3D.isChecked() and self.checkBtn_2D.isChecked():
            self.fig.clear()
            self.update_2Dfig(111,canv_ID)
            try:
                self.ax_2D_1.title.set_text("2D Plot of Pressure against Distance")
                self.ax_2D_1.set_xlabel("distance from vent [ft]")
                self.ax_2D_1.set_ylabel("Measured Pressure")
                self.canvas.draw()
            except AttributeError:
                True
        elif not self.checkBtn_2D.isChecked() and not self.checkBtn_3D.isChecked():
            self.fig.clear()
            self.canvas.draw()
        
    elif canv_ID == 2:
        if self.checkright_3D.isChecked() and self.checkright_2D.isChecked():
            self.update_3Dfig(333,canv_ID)
            try:
                self.ax_2D_2.title.set_text("2D Plot of Pressure against Distance")
                self.ax_2D_2.set_xlabel("distance from vent [ft]")
                self.ax_2D_2.set_ylabel("Measured Pressure")
                self.canvas_2.draw()
            except AttributeError:
                True
        elif self.checkright_3D.isChecked() and not self.checkright_2D.isChecked():
            self.update_3Dfig(111,canv_ID)
            try:
                self.ax_3D_2.title.set_text("3D Plot of Pressure against Distance")
                self.ax_3D_2.set_xlabel("distance from vent [ft]")
                self.ax_3D_2.set_ylabel("Time [mins]")
                self.ax_3D_2.set_zlabel("Measured Pressure")
                self.canvas_2.draw()
            except AttributeError:
                True
        elif not self.checkright_3D.isChecked() and self.checkright_2D.isChecked():
            self.fig_2.clear()
            self.update_2Dfig(111,canv_ID)
            try:
                self.ax_2D_2.title.set_text("2D Plot of Pressure against Distance")
                self.ax_2D_2.set_xlabel("distance from vent [ft]")
                self.ax_2D_2.set_ylabel("Measured Pressure")
                self.canvas_2.draw()
            except AttributeError:
                True
        elif not self.checkright_2D.isChecked() and not self.checkright_3D.isChecked():
            self.fig_2.clear()
            self.canvas_2.draw()
        
    

def update_2Dfig(self,subplot,canv_ID):
    try: self.dicti
    except AttributeError:
        return
    
    if canv_ID == 1:
        self.ax_2D_1 = self.fig.add_subplot(subplot)
        self.change_figure()
    elif canv_ID ==2:
        self.ax_2D_2 = self.fig_2.add_subplot(subplot)
        self.change_fig_2()

    
def update_3Dfig(self,subplot,canv_ID):
    try: self.dicti
    except AttributeError:
        return
    
    if canv_ID == 1:
        self.ax_3D_1 = self.fig.add_subplot(subplot,projection = '3d')
        self.change_figure()
    elif canv_ID == 2:
        self.ax_3D_2 = self.fig_2.add_subplot(subplot,projection = '3d')
        self.change_fig_2()
    
    
def change_figure(self):
    try: self.dicti
    except AttributeError:
        return
    try:
        self.ax_2D_1.clear()
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            self.ax_3D_1.clear()
        except AttributeError:
            return
    else:
        try:
            self.ax_3D_1.clear()
        except AttributeError:
            True
            
    plotting_data = []
    plotting_time = []
    plotting_dist = []
    
    plotting_data_rl = []
    plotting_time_rl = []
    plotting_dist_rl = []
    
    P_vals = {}
    T_vals = {}
    for i in range(self.slider.value()[0],self.slider.value()[1]+1):
        P_vals[i] = list()
        T_vals[i] = list()
        
        for j in self.col_titles:
            if j.lower() == 'time' or j.lower() == 'x':
                continue
            P_vals[i].append(self.dicti[j][i])
            T_vals[i].append(self.dicti[j][i])
        
        x=np.linspace(min(self.x_vals),max(self.x_vals),100)
        poly = np.polyfit(self.x_vals, P_vals[i], deg=6)
        data_fit = np.poly1d(poly)(x)
        x_bar = self.do_the_math_dummy(x,data_fit)
        x_bar_real = self.do_the_math_dummy(self.x_vals,P_vals[i])
        
        
        for j in range(0,100): plotting_time.append(i)
        for j in x: plotting_dist.append(j)
        for j in data_fit: plotting_data.append(j)
        
        for j in range(0,len(self.x_vals)): plotting_time_rl.append(i)
        for j in self.x_vals: plotting_dist_rl.append(j)
        for j in P_vals[i]: plotting_data_rl.append(j)
    
        if self.poly_lft.isChecked() and not self.fill_lft.isChecked():
            try:
                self.ax_2D_1.plot(x,data_fit)
            except AttributeError:
                self.ax_3D_1.plot(x,[i]*len(x),data_fit)          
            else:
                try:
                    self.ax_3D_1.plot(x,[i]*len(x),data_fit) 
                except AttributeError:
                    True
        if self.actual_lft.isChecked() and not self.fill_real_lft.isChecked():
            try:
                self.ax_2D_1.plot(self.x_vals, P_vals[i],'o--')
            except AttributeError:
                self.ax_3D_1.plot(self.x_vals,[i]*len(self.x_vals),P_vals[i],'o--')      
            else:
                try:
                    self.ax_3D_1.plot(self.x_vals,[i]*len(self.x_vals),P_vals[i],'o--')
                except AttributeError:
                    True
        if self.centroids_lft.isChecked():
            try:
                self.ax_2D_1.plot([x_bar],[max(data_fit)], '-o')
            except AttributeError:
                self.ax_3D_1.plot([x_bar],[i],[max(data_fit)], '-o')            
            else:
                try:
                    self.ax_3D_1.plot([x_bar],[i],[max(data_fit)], '-o')     
                except AttributeError:
                    True
        if self.centroids_real_lft.isChecked():
            try:
                self.ax_2D_1.plot([x_bar_real],[max(P_vals[i])], '-o')
            except AttributeError:
                self.ax_3D_1.plot([x_bar_real],[i],[max(P_vals[i])], '-o')            
            else:
                try:
                    self.ax_3D_1.plot([x_bar_real],[i],[max(P_vals[i])], '-o')     
                except AttributeError:
                    True
    if self.fill_lft.isChecked():
        try:
            # self.ax_2D_1.plot([x_bar],[max(data_fit)], '-o')
            verts = [(x[0], 0)] + list(zip(x, data_fit)) + [(x[len(x)-1], 0)]
            poly = Polygon(verts, facecolor = '0.9', edgecolor = '0.5')
            self.ax_2D_1.add_patch(poly)
        except AttributeError:
            my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
            trisurf = self.ax_3D_1.plot_trisurf(plotting_dist,plotting_time,plotting_data,
                         cmap = my_cmap,
                         linewidth = 0.2,
                         antialiased = True,
                         edgecolor = 'grey') 
            # self.ax_3D_1.colorbar(trisurf, ax = self.ax_3D_1, shrink = 0.5, aspect = 5)            
        else:
            try:
                my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
                trisurf = self.ax_3D_1.plot_trisurf(plotting_dist,plotting_time,plotting_data,
                             cmap = my_cmap,
                             linewidth = 0.2,
                             antialiased = True,
                             edgecolor = 'grey') 
                # self.ax_3D_1.colorbar(trisurf, ax = self.ax_3D_1, shrink = 0.5, aspect = 5)
            except AttributeError:
                True
    # elif self.fill_lft.isChecked() and self.poly_lft.isChecked() and self.actual_lft.isChecked():
    #     self.fill_lft.setChecked(False)
    if self.fill_real_lft.isChecked():
        try:
            verts = [(self.x_vals[0], 0)] + list(zip(self.x_vals, P_vals[i])) + [(self.x_vals[len(self.x_vals)-1], 0)]
            poly = Polygon(verts, facecolor = '0.9', edgecolor = '0.5')
            self.ax_2D_1.add_patch(poly)
        except AttributeError:
            my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
            trisurf = self.ax_3D_1.plot_trisurf(plotting_dist_rl,plotting_time_rl,plotting_data_rl,
                         cmap = my_cmap,
                         linewidth = 0.2,
                         antialiased = True,
                         edgecolor = 'grey') 
            # self.ax_3D_1.colorbar(trisurf, ax = self.ax_3D_1, shrink = 0.5, aspect = 5)            
        else:
            try:
                my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
                trisurf = self.ax_3D_1.plot_trisurf(plotting_dist_rl,plotting_time_rl,plotting_data_rl,
                             cmap = my_cmap,
                             linewidth = 0.2,
                             antialiased = True,
                             edgecolor = 'grey') 
                # self.ax_3D_1.colorbar(trisurf, ax = self.ax_3D_1, shrink = 0.5, aspect = 5)
            except AttributeError:
                True
    # elif self.fill_lft.isChecked() and self.poly_lft.isChecked() and self.actual_lft.isChecked():
    #     self.fill_lft.setChecked(False)
    try:
        self.ax_2D_1.set_xticks(self.x_vals)
        self.ax_2D_1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.LinearLocator(10))
        
        self.ax_2D_1.set_yticks(range(0,math.ceil(max(plotting_data_rl)),1))
        self.ax_2D_1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator(4))
        
        self.ax_2D_1.grid(which='major', color='grey', linewidth=0.8)
        self.ax_2D_1.grid(which='minor', color='red', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.7)
    except AttributeError:
        True
    try:
        self.ax_3D_1.set_xticks(self.x_vals)
        self.ax_3D_1.set_yticks(range(0,max(plotting_time),5))
        self.ax_3D_1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator(5))
        self.ax_3D_1.set_zticks(range(0,math.ceil(max(plotting_data_rl)),1))
        self.ax_3D_1.zaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator(4))
        
        self.ax_3D_1.grid(which='major', color='grey', linewidth=0.8)
        self.ax_3D_1.grid(which='minor', color='red', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.7)
    except AttributeError:
        True
    # self.fig.xticks(list(plt.xticks()[0]) + self.x_vals)
    self.canvas.draw()
```

I apologize for not initially adding code. Given the scope of this question I am unsure if a small sample or a large sample would more adequately provide insight into the nature of my issue/ability.

Comment: Lines of code are not indicative of slow responsiveness, the *quality* of the code is. Unfortunately, without any reference to compare to (for instance, the list of used modules), we cannot provide valid answers, but only try to "guess".

Comment: @musicamante I added as much code as possible but understand that there is quite a bit. I took this from my file which finds the centroid of the area under a graph and plots in 2d/3d. I wanted the format to be highly manipulable by the user. So they could easily make both graphs, overlay different data, aswell as overlay 2d/3d graphs with different sizing. In terms of quality of code, I admit I haven't been critiqued for gui design before so I can't claim to have created an efficiently designed app. Any criticism is appreciated.

Comment: what is the runetime of the application without using pyinstaller, how sure are you that pyinstaller is the one causing such a long startup time ? 10 minutes is quite a long time, even for `onefile`.

Comment: For an executable? I can't be sure. I found greatest support for using the pyinstaller method than anything else. Running it from prompt, maybe one or two seconds. @AhmedAEK

Comment: @MagicDave Please don't put **all** your code. Try to cut it down to a [mre] (gradually remove parts of the code until the problem doesn't happen anymore). It will also help to know your OS, python/Qt versions and how/from where you're running the complied binary.

Answer (score 0):

the `onefile` method stores all the dependencies (dynamic libraries and data) in a compressed form inside your executable and extracts it to a temporary folder when you start your application, this will take some time depending on how fast your hard drive and CPU are.

files are extracted in `/tmp` on linux or `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp` on windows, [but it can be changed](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-runtime-tmpdir)

in short don't use `onefile` for large applications, or when you need a fast startup, instead you should use `onedir`, to avoid the extraction process.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I was able to decrease the launch time by using onedir but not substantially. I rewrote my module calls to be specific and deleted unused ones but my launch time is still quite long. How should I streamline code design to decrease launch time?